# Disabling TLS 1.0 breaks ClickOnce setup

Tags: clickonce

We have a White Hat requirement to disable TLS 1.0 on our web server.

However, when we do this we can no longer install ClickOnce applications from the server. The setup.exe downloads, but we get the error below when the setup is started:

- Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

  ```
  - Source: System
  - Stack trace:
      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read()
      at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket()
      at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob()
      at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob()
      at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication()
      at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication()
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal()
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run()
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run()
      at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication()
      at System.Net.TlsStream.Write()
      at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders()

  --- Inner Exception ---
  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
  - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  - Source: System
  - Stack trace:
      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
  ```

Examining the packets with Wireshark reveals that the setup.exe file is sending a Client Hello message via 1.0. This is the problem because the server can't respond to the 1.0 message.

I understand the requirement to disable TLS is rather newish, but googling on the issue turned up nothing.

Has anyone experienced this before or have any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: did you find a solution for this on? i have this same problem but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Sort of. Our solution was to set up a separate web server with TLS 1.0 enabled and *just* host our ClickOnce apps there. That let us turn off TLS 1.0 on our main web server (which made the White Hat guys happy) and no one cares about the other server because all it has is the ClickOnce app.

Comment: I tried publishing setup via VS 2013 and converting project to .NET 4.5, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess now with a [release of .net 4.6.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/#clickonce) this one is solved (TLS 1.1 and 1.2 protocols supported in ClickOnce). You should get your build server patched (either [4.5.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3146710) or [4.6.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3146716)) and build your Click Once.

Comment: Does it need to be built using 4.6.2 (or similar) or can a user install it if it was built with an older version (e.g. 4.5) but has 4.6.2 installed? We're getting mixed results -- we have an application built with 4.5 and some people can't install it even with 4.6.1 installed, but I was able to.